# Webアプリケーションのサービス側と管理機能のあり方について

Tags: http

WordpressやPythonのDjango、RubyonRailsのECパッケージSpreeなど多くのアプリケーションでサービスサイトと管理機能を同じドメイン配下にしているケースを拝見します。

例）www.someservice.com・・・サービスサイト、www.someservice.com/admin・・・管理機能

当然同じサーバ上に機能を搭載している関係上セキュリティ的には不安があるのですが、この作りというのは世界共通なのでしょうか？
個人的には管理機能はサブドメインつけて別サーバに載せてアクセスするIPを限定

例）www.someservice.com / admin.someservice.com

とかするのがドメイン設計上好ましいと思っているのですが、皆さんはどのようにお考えでしょうか？

Comment: 同じサーバー上に機能を搭載しているとセキュリティ上何を不安に感じますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね。URLがわかればクラッキングされて侵入されてしまうのではないかという部分でしょうか。WordPressだと/wp-adminのようなアドレスのケースが多いので侵入される不安があります。URL変えればいいという考え方もありますが、不安は払拭できないです。

Comment: URL変えても不安であればドメイン変えても不安はかわらないのでは？

Comment: 質問の仕方が悪かったかもです。世の中にあるアプリケーションのパッケージの大半が公開画面と管理画面を同じドメイン配下（同一アプリケーション）として作られているのを見て、なぜ管理機能と公開画面は分ける設計にしないのかふと疑問に感じたので、お聞きしたい感じでした。これってスタンダードなんですかね？

Comment: なぜアプリケーションを分ける必要があると思ったのかを書いてもらえればそれにそって解答が出来るかなと思いましたが、特には理由はないということですかね？

Comment: アプリケーションを分ける必要があると思ったのは、今までの現場でサービスサイトと管理機能は別ドメイン（別サーバ）にしているところが多かったからです。ですが、上記に挙げたWordPressなどはアプリケーション内にサービスページと管理ページを内包(https://wordpresssite.comとhttps://wordpresssite.com/wp-admin）しているケースも見られたのでこういう形式もスタンダードなのかを伺おうとしておりました。わかりづらくてすみません。

Answer (score 0):

正解のない質問はアンケート扱いで SO 的には非推奨ですが
ドメイン名を複数維持管理するには（提示例では `wwww.example.com` と `admin.example.com` の両者) １つだけ取得するより余計にコストがかかります。セキュリティもコストを無視しては語れません。その辺、立場の違いで話は違ってくるでしょう

- 既存のフレームワーク類を一切使用せずに独自プログラムで独自ドメインを維持するサイト管理者なら
  そういうところはたいてい自鯖を立てているでしょう。なら維持管理はコンソールから行えばよいのでサブドメインにコストは払いたくないです。
- Web フレームワークの作者なら
  フレームワークのユーザーつまりはサイト管理者に対してサブドメインを維持するコストを負担させるか否かってことになりそう。サイト管理者に追加の維持コストを強いる分、フレームワークのユーザーは増えないかもしれません（フレームワーク間の競争面で不利）。仮にこのフレームワークの出来が良いなどの理由によりユーザーが増えたとして、サンプルないしはドキュメントに「管理用に `admin.example.com` を作れ」と記載したらそのまま真似るユーザーは一定数居ますし、当然ながら攻撃者もその辺の状況を真似るでしょう。その意味でセキュリティが向上するとは思えません。
- 普通に既存の web フレームワークを使うサイト作者なら
  わざわざサブドメインを作り `admin.example.com` にログインできる IP アドレスを制限するなら、そりゃ `www.example.com` で行ってもセキュリティ的に大差はないはずなのでサブドメインを立てる根拠にならんです（オイラがスポンサーとして金出す側ならそんなことは却下）

ってことでオイラの意見としては「セキュリティが増すか減るかだけ考えるなら、サブドメインを作るほうがセキュリティが増すかもしれないが、同じ程度に終わる可能性のほうが高い」です。根拠は「攻撃者もそんなことは百も承知なので本気で攻撃したいようなクラッカーには通じないだろう」「カジュアルな攻撃者やスクリプトキディ避けにはなるかもしれない」ってとこで。まとめると「金をかけるべき場所が間違っていないか要検討」ってとこでしょう。

Comment: ご回答あありがとうございます！すみません。アンケートという機能があるのを存じませんでした。なるほど、管理機能を別サーバにしても多少効果あってもリスク回避にはならないということですね。コストも含めて比較検討してみます。

Answer (score 0):

> 個人的には管理機能はサブドメインつけて別サーバに載せてアクセスするIPを限定
>
> 例）www.someservice.com / admin.someservice.com
>
> とかするのがドメイン設計上好ましいと思っているのですが、皆さんはどのようにお考えでしょうか？

・別のサブドメインをつける
・別サーバに乗せる
・アクセス元のIPアドレスを限定する

これはそれぞれ独立した話で、トータルではドメイン設計のはなしではないですね。

・同じサーバでドメインが別
・同じサーバで同じドメインだけど管理領域は接続できるIPアドレスを制限
・ドメイン同じだけど実体は別サーバ

という構成もあり得ます。

質問を読むと、ドメインではなく「サービスと管理が同じサーバに乗っている」ことが問題であると考えられているようです。上に書いたように、同一サーバで管理領域だけIPアドレスベースでアクセスを制限する、ということも考えられますがこれではNGという話になるので、サービス側は公開、管理側はFWの内側など非公開の領域に配置する構成を暗に想定されているのではなでしょうか。

確かに管理側を攻撃されるリスクは減りますが、設備を用意するコスト、データベースをどっちに置いてその通信をどう制御するのかとか、FWの運用はどうするんだとか考えないといけないこと、構成が複雑になったことで生じるリスクはそれ以上のものになることは容易に想像できます。

結局、ほとんどのユースケースではそんなことを強制する意味がない訳です。

となればWordPressやSpreeみたいなアプリケーション観点では「ミニマムな構成」が前提になるのでサーバ１台で動く構成になります。運用者がどうしても「サービスと管理を分離したい」というのであれば別にできないことはないと思います。

Django(やWAF全般)はそれ自体が「サービスと管理が一体」であることを強制してるわけではないでしょう。それ使ってアプリケーションを作る人がどう作るか次第です。

逆に、上に書いたようなサーバとネットワークを分離するコストが最初から見込まれている規模のアプリケーションであれば、サービスと管理が分離されていることはいろいろメリットになります。

Comment: ふむふむ、ありがとうございます！どちらにも長所短所があり、コストや要件次第で決めればいいということですね。

Answer (score 0):

サブディレクトリに見えてもリバースプロキシを使って別サーバに振り分けているかもしれないし、反対に別ドメインに見えてもヴァーチャルホストの機能を使って実は同一サーバな場合もあり得ますので、ドメイン名やURLだけで安全性を判断するのは早計かと。

同一サーバ上でもディレクトリごとで適切なアクセス制限をかける運用も考えられますし(管理用のURLには特定のネットワークからしか許可しない等)、例えサーバを分けたとしてもネットワーク的に繋がっているならリスクがゼロになるわけでもないと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！リバースプロキシで別サーバに分けていたり、VHOSTで同一ホストにして管理機能を設置しているパターンは今までの現場ではありませんでした。参考にさせていただきます。